# Browsersync loading forever

Tags: laravel, browser-sync

I'm using Browsersync with Laravel:

```
npm run watch
```

Code is compiled and Browsersync is launched.

However, the page stays blank and loads forever.

http://localhost:3001/ works fine and displays the dashboard from Browsersync.

However, http://localhost:3000/my-project/ or http://192.168.0.15:3000/my-project/ load forever...

I found out that I was not the only one to struggle. I tried to disable the firewall, without luck...

The only workaround I found so far was to use Wamp...

Any ideas?

---

**webpack.mix.js**

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
        .version()
        .sourceMaps()
        .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
        .options({
            postCss: [
                require('postcss-css-variables')()
            ]
        });

mix.browserSync('localhost/my-project-public-folder/');
```

Comment: Show us your BrowserSync configuration code.

Comment: Just added webpack config

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution?